# Is it possible with Print.js to send the PDF to storage in a folder online instead of printing it?

Tags: pdf

I am trying to use print.js(crabbly) https://github.com/crabbly/print.js to send a PDF to a folder on my website instead of printing it.

My task is to save form data into a PDF and save the PDF in a folder on my website once the user submits. I like the way print.js creates the PDF and sends it to print but I need it to send to my folder...maybe through php?

Thanks for anyone's help!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle that form submission on the server side. Once you receive the form request or the payload, you can then use it to create your own PDF.

Looks like you may be using Php in the back-end, if that's the case, the FPDF class should have everything you need to create your PDF:
http://www.fpdf.org/

If you use Laravel, here is a convenient package wrapping the FPDF class so we can import it with composer:
https://github.com/crabbly/fpdf-laravel